# Is there a way to "grep" for a keyword in a JavaScript object in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: json, grep, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-objects

I often work with large JavaScript objects and instead of manually opening and closing "branches", I would like to simply search for a particular string and show any key or value that matches.

Sort of like "grepping" for a keyword in a JavaScript object. Is this possible (especially in Chrome Dev Tool)?

Unfortunately I was hoping I could at least try the `JSON.stringify()` trick and then search on the raw JSON in a text editor, but I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the object's keys and match against them:

```
function grepKeys(o, query){
    var ret = {};
    Object.keys(o).filter(function(key){
       return key.includes(query);
    }).forEach(function(key){ // can reduce instead
       ret[key] = o[key]; // copy over
    });
    return ret;
}
```

Which'd let you return a partial object with all the keys that contain the string you specified. Note that this will not show any prototype keys but can be easily extended to allow it (by using a `for... in` instead of an Object.keys or by using recursion):

```
 var o = grepKeys({buzz:5, fuzz:3, foo:4}, "zz");
 o; // Object {buzz: 5, fuzz: 3}
```